# Jquery id selector not working on INTERNET EXPLORER

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Why this does not work ON INTERNET EXPLORER:

I have this html input tag. I call my js function to do some staff on the toprint element. In FF, chrome it works. But on IE I get "missing argument error".

```
<input type="button" onclick="PrintElem('#ToPrint')" value="<?php echo t("DOWNLOAD");?>" />
```

The div element is somewhere in the page like:

```
    <div class="letterBody paddingLg LmarginXlg"  id="ToPrint">
<p>bla bla</p>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


    function PrintElem(elem)

    {

        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data)

    {

        var mywindow = window.open('', 'Press Release');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title><?php echo $data->title  ;?></title>');
        mywindow.document.write(' <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo base_path().$directory; ?>/css/printA4.css"/>');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body  onload="" class="printA4">');
        mywindow.document.write(data);

/*
                $(document).ready(function() {
                this.title = '<?php echo $data->title  ;?>'


                 var salonLogo =   $("#salonLogo").attr("src")
                 var imgSalonLogo = salonLogo.search("salonlogo")
                 if(imgSalonLogo == -1){
                     $("#salonLogo").attr("src","")
                 }


                })
*/

        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        mywindow.document.close();
        mywindow.print();
        return true;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
    this.title = '<?php echo $data->title  ;?>'
    })

</script>
```

Comment: please describe your error. IE version?? error on which line no.?? format proper

Comment: But what happens on ie? No popup? Popup with wrong value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is probably in this line:

```
var mywindow = window.open('', 'Press Release');
```

in IE, the window name must not contain spaces, because it gets mapped to a `window` variable.

Use something like

```
var mywindow = window.open('', 'PressRelease');
```

Please in the future, always show the exact line the error is happening in, and  the exact error - I think it complained about an *invalid* argument, not a *missing* one.

Comment: yUP? WONDERFUL PAEKKA. OK FOR THE ADVICE